# How can we offer (and track) multiple premiums for a single contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, premiums

We are a small museum that is converting an existing membership program to CiviCRM. Our current membership program offers, say, 10 free admissions/year with the purchase of a Gold Membership and 5 free admissions with the a Silver Membership. I know how to set up the CiviCRM Price Sets for the different membership types. What type of field could I use to track **and report** the number free admissions used by each member? The entry of the free admissions could be done by staff at the back end as each free admission is used.
(CiviCRM 5.48.0 on WordPress 5.9.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a really manual set up, if you set up a number field (Free Entries Remaining) on the specific Membership Types, and set it to start as Default = 5 (for Silver) or 10 (for Gold), then each time a member uses a freebie your admin drop the value by 1

Comment: Perfect.  I know really manual is a crude approach but it's in scale to our resources and our anticipated volumes don't justify anything grander.